# Node + SQL Column cannot be null

Tags: mysql, node.js, rest

I used `node` and `mysql` for building rest api, but when I use the `POST` method I am getting **Column 'xxx' cannot be null**. I am not understanding where I am going wrong . I tried in few other sites, but I din't understand properly.

```
app.post('/info', function(req,res) {
connection.query('INSERT into task(id,title,status) values(?,?,?)',
    [req.body.id, req.body.title, req.body.status], function(error, rows, fields) {
        if (error) {
            console.log(error);
        } else {
            res.json(rows);
        }
    })
```

});

Please let me know where I am going wrong. Any help/advice greatly appreciated.

Comment: alter table structure, remove column name 'XXX'  not null constraint

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at your SQL schema, or the statements you used to define your columns in your tables. There is a column that you have defined as NOT NULL and this INSERT statement does not POST any data to the column defined as NOT NULL and that is why you are getting that error. You have to POST data to **Column 'xxx'**.

You can fix this by eliminating the NOT NULL constraint from **Column 'xxx'** if it does not need to be initialized with data on every query.

Comment: hope it helps. Let me know if turns out to be the answer to your problem.

Comment: what you said is right. But  i need to define the null. If it's not null it should get inserted and if it's null data should not get insert

Comment: Wanna post your schema? let me take a look.

Answer (score 0):

If I set all the values to "NOT NULL" it worked perfectly fine. But the data is not getting reflected in the MySQL Database.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).